# Stokes theorem for manifolds with boundary as disjoint union of submanifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, measure-theory, smooth-manifolds, integration, geometric-measure-theory

Looking at the generalizations of Stokes theorem, I did find a version for manifold with corners, but I was surprised this generalization doesn't contain a simple example such as the cone. So my question is the following :

Is the following version of Stokes theorem correct?

Let $M$ be a smooth submanifold without boundary of $\mathbb{R}^N$ of dimension $n\leq N$, and suppose that the topological boundary $\partial M$ of $M$ is the finite disjoint union of (smooth) submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}^N$, each of them of dimension $\leq n-1$.
Then for all $n-1$ form on $\mathbb{R}^N$ with compact support, we have $\int_M d\omega = \sum_i \int_{B_i} \omega$, where $(B_i)$ are all the submanifolds of dimension $n-1$ in the decomposition of $\partial M$.

I am aware of a generalization of Stokes theorem that contains the cone, that is in the book of
*Partial Differential Equations 1* of Sauvigny, where  the notion of "singular set with capacity zero" is described, but I admit I don't understand what it means. I suppose (but I am not sure) that the previous statement is true if one can show that submanifolds of dimension $\leq n-2$ in the topological boundary of $M$ are with capacity zero with respect to $M$ in the sense of Sauvigny. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** Yes, i think this is correct and should follow directly from a general version of Stokes's theorem in Geometric Measure Theory.

Recall that a rectifiable set of dimension $m$ in ${\bf R}^n$ is a set of finite $m$-dimensional Hausdorff measure almost contained (wrt this measure) in the union of images of countably many Lipschitz functions from ${\bf R}^m$ to ${\bf R}^n$. Manifolds with boundaries, cones, etc are of course rectifiable.

The Stokes's theorem is valid for any rectifiable set with compact support. Actually this is a tautology because Stokes' formula is used to define the boundary of such a set as a rectifiable current (i.e as a linear form on the sets of differential forms, or equivalently as a differential form with distribution coefficients).

So the question is, when does the boundary of a rectifiable set is associated to a rectifiable set itself, such as to give a geometric meaning to the boundary? The Closure Theorem from Geometric Measure Theory implies that the boundary is a rectifiable set if and only if it has finite mass.

A general reference is the book *"Geometric Measure Theory"* by H. Federer.
If you are not interested in the lengthy and technical proofs, you can instead read the shorter book *"Geometric Measure Theory, a beginner's guide"* by Frank Morgan (chapter 4) which surveys the whole theory.

The first step in the theory is to define a notion of a tangent cone at a given point of a measurable set and to show that if the set is m-rectifiable, then this cone is actually an m-dimensional plane almost everywhere.

Comment: Thank you, that helps a lot. Just so that I understand a little bit more the details, I have a few questions.  1) What do you mean by rectifiable set with compact support ? 2) What does it mean for a rectifiable set to have finite mass? 3) How to show that a finite union of submanifolds of dimension $\leq n-1$ has finite mass? 4) Does this imply that we must rectrict to boundaries with finite hausdorff measure ?

Comment: For a set, compat support just means that the closure is compact. The mass of a rectifiable set is the Haussdorff measure of the set counting multiplicities.  So for a finite union of manifolds, you just have to show that the n-1 Haussdorff measure of each pieces  is finite.